# Switching between Scene and Activity

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am developing a game where I am using andengine SceneManager to manage various scenes. In one scene I have a button which passes control to a class that extends activity (not scene) and uses an XML file for layout.

My problem is that in that activity I have a button. Clicking on that button should open a scene. I am using the following syntax to open a scene but it doesn't do anything.

```
SceneManager.getInstance().loadPreLevel(engine, "levelfail");
```

where SceneManager is the scenemanager class and loadPreLevel is a method that I use to open activate loading scene and this line of code works everywhere else in my game.

Does anyone know how to open a scene from an Activity's subclass.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Your game structure is not so good like at all. It's Better to keep only one Activity to Initialize the game start up and rest of Scene will extends scene including Splash!

I would suggest to look [this](http://www.matim-dev.com/how-to-design-your-game-useful-concept-pattern.html) article to clearing the concept about activity versus scene.

Comment: I know that but I want to impliment google in app billing and i was unable to make it working in a scene as it need override some Activity classe's methods that can be done by extending from Activity.

Comment: anyone have any other solution?